# error 404 url not found using fetch to post in express.js

Tags: javascript, express, post, http-status-code-404, fetch-api

Code fails to find url when attempting a fetch in order to POST, note that i'm using node.js and express.js

Code spitting out the error:

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form');

form.addEventListener('submit', async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

    const data = new FormData(form);

    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/app', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        prompt: data.get('input'),
      }),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    })

});
```

The origin of the url not being found:

```js
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

app.post('/app', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    
    const response = 'test'

    res.send({ response });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
});
app.listen(8080)
```

I've attempted changing the url in the post and fetch to the following variations:

```js
'http://localhost:8080/app'

'/app'

'./app'

'app'

'localhost:8080/app'

'http://localhost:8080'
```

Comment: `app.post('http://localhost:8080/app'` should be `app.post('/app'` - where is your `app.listen` line though?

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be coming from the way you define the route in your express server.

When defining a route in Express.js, you don't include the base URL (i.e., `'http://localhost:8080/'`). Express only needs the endpoint, or the path after the base URL. In your case, this should be `'/app'`.

Change your code from this

```
app.post('http://localhost:8080/app', async (req, res) => {
```

to this

```
app.post('/app', async (req, res) => {
```

and your problem should be solved.

You should not however, change the URL inside the `fetch()` function.
This line should stay as it is:

```
const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/app', {
```

Comment: you may want to add that OP should NOT change the URL in the `fetch` ... seems they tried all sorts of combinations (including your solution) - but were changing BOTH the app.post and the fetch to be identical - at least, that's what I think they were doing

Comment: You are right. I will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't appear to fix the error

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the code you've provided. It should be working. Try adding a callback function to the end of your `app.listen()` function as so `app.listen(8080, () => {console.log("Listening on port 8080.")})`. Are you sure you are running the client and server in different environments? Can you add an `app.get()` function to check if your server is reachable through the client?